# raco docs change default firefox browser

Tags: ubuntu, documentation, racket

Hopefully it belongs here.

My default browser is `chromium` and racket's `raco docs` doesn't care -> launches firefox anyway. A bit of googling and `man raco` show no pertinent settings. Even kinda embarrassed to ask. But I vaguely recall from couple years back the same problem with my previous `racket` installation.

And since no obvious settings it may not be ubuntu-specific (though decided to tag). After all browser seems to be help default mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open DrRacket. Go to Preferences and click the Browser tab. You should see radio buttons there that let you select the browser you would like to use. That setting should transfer to `raco` as well.

In my DrRacket, it doesn't show Chrome as an option, but you should be able to set a custom browser. You may need to put `"chromium "` (with the space) to get it to work.

Comment: Yep thanks works nicely. Though honestly didn't expect so tight drracket/raco coupling (looked for some dotfile). Prefer emacs. Also for those interested the settings actually are stored in `~/.racket/racket-prefs.rktd`. Not sure if intended for manual editing.

Comment: You don't have to use DrRacket, it's just the easiest way. You can also require the `browser/external` library and call `(update-browser-preference #f)` for a GUI or use `put-preferences` manually.

Comment: Cool. :) Like more options. Only it's weird that google search for "racket browser/external" refers to 5.2 racket and nothing else relevant on the first page.